# Valid input mask with angularjs (ui-mask)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

i got some problem when i was making input mask using ui-mask in angularJs.I'm chechking if the written string is correct then textarea must become green.But in my case, textarea initially is green, then when you type some word it becomes red untill you type correct word. I will post my code and if you can help me to solve that problem, i dont know how to do more i tried a lot of things but nothing worked.Sorry guys for so huge script. heres my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>I am Tom</title>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angularjs/mask.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angularjs/module.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myController">

    <div class="divito">

        <h3 clas="h3">Please Input following text: I am Tom</h3>

        <textarea class="textarea" style="resize: none" cols="30" row="2" ui-mask="i am tom" ng-model="greeting" data-ng-trim="fasle" ng-trim="false"> 
        </textarea>

    </div>  

  </body>

</html>
```

Style.css

```
body{
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
}
.textarea{
    width:600px;
    height:60px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 43px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.divito { 
    margin: 200px 30% 0 33%;
    position: relative;
 }

textarea.ng-invalid {
    border:2px solid #EA4335;
}
textarea.ng-valid {
    background-color:lightgreen;
}
```

And here is my script.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]); 

app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.greeting = '123456789';
  }]).directive('uiMask', [
  function () {
    var maskDefinitions = {
      // 'I': /[I-i]/,
      // '2': /[a]/,
      // '3': /[m]/,
      // '4': /[T]/,
      // '5': /[o]/
      'a': /[a]/,   'A': /[A]/, 
      'b': /[b]/,   'B': /[B]/,
      'c': /[c]/,   'C': /[C]/,
      'd': /[d]/,   'D': /[D]/,
      'e': /[e]/,   'E': /[E]/,
      'f': /[f]/,   'F': /[F]/,
      'g': /[g]/,   'G': /[G]/,
      'h': /[h]/,   'H': /[H]/,
      'i': /[i]/,   'I': /[I]/,
      'j': /[j]/,   'J': /[J]/,
      'k': /[h]/,   'K': /[K]/,
      'l': /[l]/,   'L': /[L]/,
      'm': /[m]/,   'M': /[M]/,
      'n': /[n]/,   'N': /[N]/,
      'o': /[o]/,   'O': /[O]/,
      'p': /[p]/,   'P': /[P]/,
      'q': /[q]/,   'Q': /[Q]/,
      'r': /[r]/,   'R': /[R]/,
      's': /[s]/,   'S': /[S]/,
      't': /[t]/,   'T': /[T]/,
      'u': /[u]/,   'U': /[U]/,
      'v': /[v]/,   'V': /[V]/,
      'w': /[w]/,   'W': /[W]/,
      'x': /[x]/,   'X': /[X]/,
      'y': /[y]/,   'Y': /[Y]/,
      'z': /[z]/,   'Z': /[Z]/
    };
    return {
      priority: 100,
      require: 'ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
            //console.log('init');
        var maskProcessed = false, eventsBound = false,
            maskCaretMap, maskPatterns, maskPlaceholder, maskComponents,
            validValue,
            // Minimum required length of the value to be considered valid
            minRequiredLength,
            value, valueMasked, isValid,
            // Vars for initializing/uninitializing
            originalPlaceholder = iAttrs.placeholder,
            originalMaxlength   = iAttrs.maxlength,
            // Vars used exclusively in eventHandler()
            oldValue, oldValueUnmasked, oldCaretPosition, oldSelectionLength;

        function initialize(maskAttr) {
          if (!angular.isDefined(maskAttr)){
            return uninitialize();
          }
          processRawMask(maskAttr);
          if (!maskProcessed){
            return uninitialize();
          }
          initializeElement();
          bindEventListeners();
        }

        function formatter(fromModelValue) {
          if (!maskProcessed){
            return fromModelValue;
          }
          value   = unmaskValue(fromModelValue || '');
          // isValid = validateValue(value);
          // controller.$setValidity('mask', isValid);

          if (isValid) validValue = value;
          //console.log('formatter valid:'+validValue);
          return isValid && value.length ? maskValue(value) : undefined;
       }

        function parser(fromViewValue) {
          if (!maskProcessed){
            return fromViewValue;
          }
          value     = unmaskValue(fromViewValue || '');
          isValid   = validateValue(value);
          viewValue = value.length ? maskValue(value) : '';
          // We have to set viewValue manually as the reformatting of the input
          // value performed by eventHandler() doesn't happen until after
          // this parser is called, which causes what the user sees in the input
          // to be out-of-sync with what the controller's $viewValue is set to.
          controller.$viewValue = viewValue;
          controller.$setValidity('mask', isValid);
          if (value === '' && controller.$error.required !== undefined){
            controller.$setValidity('required', false);
          }
          if (isValid) validValue = value;
          //console.log('parser valid:'+validValue);
          return isValid ? value : undefined;
        }

        iAttrs.$observe('uiMask', initialize);
        controller.$formatters.push(formatter);
        controller.$parsers.push(parser);

        function uninitialize() {
          maskProcessed = false;
          unbindEventListeners();

          if (angular.isDefined(originalPlaceholder)){
            iElement.attr('placeholder', originalPlaceholder);
          }else{
            iElement.removeAttr('placeholder');
          }

          if (angular.isDefined(originalMaxlength)){
            iElement.attr('maxlength', originalMaxlength);
          }else{
            iElement.removeAttr('maxlength');
          }

          iElement.val(controller.$modelValue);
          controller.$viewValue = controller.$modelValue;
          return false;
        }

        function initializeElement() {
          value       = oldValueUnmasked = unmaskValue(controller.$modelValue || '');
          valueMasked = oldValue         = maskValue(value);
          isValid     = validateValue(value);
          viewValue   = isValid && value.length ? valueMasked : '';
          if (iAttrs.maxlength){ // Double maxlength to allow pasting new val at end of mask
            iElement.attr('maxlength', maskCaretMap[maskCaretMap.length-1]*2);
          }
          iElement.attr('placeholder', maskPlaceholder);
          iElement.val(viewValue);
          controller.$viewValue = viewValue;
          // Not using $setViewValue so we don't clobber the model value and dirty the form
          // without any kind of user interaction.
        }

        function bindEventListeners() {
          if (eventsBound){
            return true;
          }
          iElement.bind('blur',              blurHandler);
          iElement.bind('mousedown mouseup', mouseDownUpHandler);
          iElement.bind('input keyup click', eventHandler);
          eventsBound = true;
        }

        // function unbindEventListeners() {
        //   if (!eventsBound){
        //     return true;
        //   }
        //   iElement.unbind('blur',      blurHandler);
        //   iElement.unbind('mousedown', mouseDownUpHandler);
        //   iElement.unbind('mouseup',   mouseDownUpHandler);
        //   iElement.unbind('input',     eventHandler);
        //   iElement.unbind('keyup',     eventHandler);
        //   iElement.unbind('click',     eventHandler);
        //   eventsBound = false;
        // }

        function validateValue(value) {
          // Zero-length value validity is ngRequired's determination
          return value.length ? value.length >= minRequiredLength : true;
        }

        function unmaskValue(value) {
          var valueUnmasked    = '',
              maskPatternsCopy = maskPatterns.slice();
          // Preprocess by stripping mask components from value
          value = value.toString();
          angular.forEach(maskComponents, function(component, i) {
            value = value.replace(component, '');
          });
          angular.forEach(value.split(''), function(chr, i) {
            if (maskPatternsCopy.length && maskPatternsCopy[0].test(chr)) {
              valueUnmasked += chr;
              maskPatternsCopy.shift();
            }
          });
          return valueUnmasked;
        }

        function maskValue(unmaskedValue) {
          var valueMasked      = '',
              maskCaretMapCopy = maskCaretMap.slice();
          angular.forEach(maskPlaceholder.split(''), function(chr, i) {
            if (unmaskedValue.length && i === maskCaretMapCopy[0]) {
              valueMasked  += unmaskedValue.charAt(0) || '_';
              unmaskedValue = unmaskedValue.substr(1);
              maskCaretMapCopy.shift(); }
            else{
              valueMasked += chr;
            }
          });
          return valueMasked;
        }

        function processRawMask(mask) {
          var characterCount = 0;
          maskCaretMap       = [];
          maskPatterns       = [];
          maskPlaceholder    = '';

          // No complex mask support for now...
          // if (mask instanceof Array) {
          //   angular.forEach(mask, function(item, i) {
          //     if (item instanceof RegExp) {
          //       maskCaretMap.push(characterCount++);
          //       maskPlaceholder += '_';
          //       maskPatterns.push(item);
          //     }
          //     else if (typeof item == 'string') {
          //       angular.forEach(item.split(''), function(chr, i) {
          //         maskPlaceholder += chr;
          //         characterCount++;
          //       });
          //     }
          //   });
          // }
          // Otherwise it's a simple mask
          // else

          if (typeof mask === 'string') {
            minRequiredLength = 0;
            var isOptional = false;

            angular.forEach(mask.split(''), function(chr, i) {
              if (maskDefinitions[chr]) {
                maskCaretMap.push(characterCount);
                maskPlaceholder += '_';
                maskPatterns.push(maskDefinitions[chr]);

                characterCount++;
                if (!isOptional) {
                  minRequiredLength++;
                }
              }
              else if (chr === "?") {
                isOptional = true;
              }
              else{
                maskPlaceholder += chr;
                characterCount++;
              }
            });
          }
          // Caret position immediately following last position is valid.
          maskCaretMap.push(maskCaretMap.slice().pop() + 1);
          // Generate array of mask components that will be stripped from a masked value
          // before processing to prevent mask components from being added to the unmasked value.
          // E.g., a mask pattern of '+7 9999' won't have the 7 bleed into the unmasked value.
                                                                // If a maskable char is followed by a mask char and has a mask
                                                                // char behind it, we'll split it into it's own component so if
                                                                // a user is aggressively deleting in the input and a char ahead
                                                                // of the maskable char gets deleted, we'll still be able to strip
                                                                // it in the unmaskValue() preprocessing.
          maskComponents = maskPlaceholder.replace(/[_]+/g,'_').replace(/([^_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9])([^_])/g, '$1$2_$3').split('_');
          maskProcessed  = maskCaretMap.length > 1 ? true : false;
        }

        function blurHandler(e) {
          oldCaretPosition   = 0;
          oldSelectionLength = 0;
          if (!isValid || value.length === 0) {
            valueMasked = '';
            iElement.val('');
            scope.$apply(function() {
              controller.$setViewValue('');
            });
          }
        }

        function mouseDownUpHandler(e) {
          if (e.type === 'mousedown'){
            iElement.bind('mouseout', mouseoutHandler);
          }else{
            iElement.unbind('mouseout', mouseoutHandler);
          }
        }

        iElement.bind('mousedown mouseup', mouseDownUpHandler);

        function mouseoutHandler(e) {
          oldSelectionLength = getSelectionLength(this);
          iElement.unbind('mouseout', mouseoutHandler);
        }

        function eventHandler(e) {
          e = e || {};
          // Allows more efficient minification
          var eventWhich = e.which,
              eventType  = e.type;
          // Prevent shift and ctrl from mucking with old values
          if (eventWhich === 16 || eventWhich === 91){ return true;}

          var val             = iElement.val(),
              valOld          = oldValue,
              valMasked,
              valUnmasked     = unmaskValue(val),
              valUnmaskedOld  = oldValueUnmasked,
              valAltered      = false,

              caretPos        = getCaretPosition(this) || 0,
              caretPosOld     = oldCaretPosition || 0,
              caretPosDelta   = caretPos - caretPosOld,
              caretPosMin     = maskCaretMap[0],
              caretPosMax     = maskCaretMap[valUnmasked.length] || maskCaretMap.slice().shift(),

              selectionLen    = getSelectionLength(this),
              selectionLenOld = oldSelectionLength || 0,
              isSelected      = selectionLen > 0,
              wasSelected     = selectionLenOld > 0,

                                                                // Case: Typing a character to overwrite a selection
              isAddition      = (val.length > valOld.length) || (selectionLenOld && val.length >  valOld.length - selectionLenOld),
                                                                // Case: Delete and backspace behave identically on a selection
              isDeletion      = (val.length < valOld.length) || (selectionLenOld && val.length === valOld.length - selectionLenOld),
              isSelection     = (eventWhich >= 37 && eventWhich <= 40) && e.shiftKey, // Arrow key codes

              isKeyLeftArrow  = eventWhich === 37,
                                                    // Necessary due to "input" event not providing a key code
              isKeyBackspace  = eventWhich === 8  || (eventType !== 'keyup' && isDeletion && (caretPosDelta === -1)),
              isKeyDelete     = eventWhich === 46 || (eventType !== 'keyup' && isDeletion && (caretPosDelta === 0 ) && !wasSelected),

              // Handles cases where caret is moved and placed in front of invalid maskCaretMap position. Logic below
              // ensures that, on click or leftward caret placement, caret is moved leftward until directly right of
              // non-mask character. Also applied to click since users are (arguably) more likely to backspace
              // a character when clicking within a filled input.
              caretBumpBack   = (isKeyLeftArrow || isKeyBackspace || eventType === 'click') && caretPos > caretPosMin;

          oldSelectionLength  = selectionLen;

          // These events don't require any action
          if (isSelection || (isSelected && (eventType === 'click' || eventType === 'keyup'))){
            return true;
          }

          // Value Handling
          // ==============

          // User attempted to delete but raw value was unaffected--correct this grievous offense

          if ((eventType === 'input') && isDeletion && !wasSelected && valUnmasked === valUnmaskedOld) {
            while (isKeyBackspace && caretPos > caretPosMin && !isValidCaretPosition(caretPos)){
              caretPos--;
            }
            while (isKeyDelete && caretPos < caretPosMax && maskCaretMap.indexOf(caretPos) === -1){
              caretPos++;
            }
            var charIndex = maskCaretMap.indexOf(caretPos);
            // Strip out non-mask character that user would have deleted if mask hadn't been in the way.
            valUnmasked = valUnmasked.substring(0, charIndex) + valUnmasked.substring(charIndex + 1);
            valAltered  = true;
          }

          // Update values
          console.log(e);
          console.log(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode));
          //console.log(String.fromCodePoint(e.keyCode));
          //console.log("---> update values start");
          //console.log("valUnmasked:" + valUnmasked);
          //console.log("valMasked:" + valMasked);
          valMasked        = maskValue(valUnmasked);
          oldValue         = valMasked;
          oldValueUnmasked = valUnmasked;
          iElement.val(valMasked);



          // Make sure caret is within min and max position limits
          caretPos = caretPos > caretPosMax ? caretPosMax : caretPos < caretPosMin ? caretPosMin : caretPos;

          // Scoot the caret back or forth until it's in a non-mask position and within min/max position limits
          while (!isValidCaretPosition(caretPos) && caretPos > caretPosMin && caretPos < caretPosMax){
            caretPos += caretBumpBack ? -1 : 1;
          }

          if ((caretBumpBack && caretPos < caretPosMax) || (isAddition && !isValidCaretPosition(caretPosOld))){
            caretPos++;
          }
          oldCaretPosition = caretPos;
          setCaretPosition(this, caretPos);
        }

        function isValidCaretPosition(pos) { return maskCaretMap.indexOf(pos) > -1; }

        function getCaretPosition(input) {
          if (input.selectionStart !== undefined){
            return input.selectionStart;
          }else if (document.selection) {
            // Curse you IE
            input.focus();
            var selection = document.selection.createRange();
            selection.moveStart('character', -input.value.length);
            return selection.text.length;
          }
        }

        function setCaretPosition(input, pos) {
          if (input.offsetWidth === 0 || input.offsetHeight === 0){
            return true; // Input's hidden
          }
          if (input.setSelectionRange) {
            input.focus();
            input.setSelectionRange(pos,pos); }
          else if (input.createTextRange) {
            // Curse you IE
            var range = input.createTextRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.moveEnd('character', pos);
            range.moveStart('character', pos);
            range.select();
          }
        }

        function getSelectionLength(input) {
          if (input.selectionStart !== undefined){
            return (input.selectionEnd - input.selectionStart);
          }
          if (document.selection){
            return (document.selection.createRange().text.length);
          }
        }


      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Comment: please reduce your example, see also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: how can i reduce? just remove unneed lines ?

Comment: strip it down to a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution, i just needed to add this in css.

```
textarea.ng-dirty.ng-invalid {
    border:2px solid #EA4335;
}
textarea.ng-dirty.ng-valid {
    background-color:lightgreen;
}
```

and now it works fine.